# How can I specify the path in Makefile

Tags: go, makefile, protocol-buffers, proto

I would like to add makefile for my go project. It always can't run seems caused by specify path error, the exception is as below:

```
protoc -I=../proto --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go_out=../proto/ ../proto/userinfo.proto
protoc-gen-go: program not found or is not executable
Please specify a program using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH system variable
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: Plugin failed with status code 1.
make: *** [proto] Error 1

Process finished with exit code 2
```

command for this part in Makefile is as below:

```
proto:
    protoc -I=../proto --go_opt=paths=source_relative --go_out=../proto/ ../proto/userinfo.proto
```

but when I `cd proto` dir and run this command, it's correct, `*pb.go` can be generated

my project structure is as below:`makefile` is located different dir with `proto` file, how can I write this makefile?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages — instead, post the actual code and error messages. Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: done, I have edited it again, can check

Comment: Can you clarify the make command: what is the working directory when you type 'make', and what are the command line arguments ? Also, can you clarify the commands use to make it work: is it 'cd proto ; make' ?

Comment: I command `make` in `service` directory where the `Makefile` file located in, I didn't `cd proto`, I just test `proto` command by `cd proto`

Comment: Did you solve this issue I am facing the same error from Makefile?